# Centos server reboots itself

Tags: centos, logging

I am running centos 6.x on my server. It rebooted itself at 10.30am and 11.13am today.

I checked /var/log/messages file and couldn't understand. What can be cause to reboot?

My log file (I couldn't paste it here because character limit):

http://pastebin.com/R9VN3nSJ

Answer (score 0):

Check your servers memory by memtest86+. You can install it on the Centos system:

```
# yum -y install memtest86+
# memtest-setup
```

Then reboot system and choose memtest at boot grub menu.
Before all you need to ensure that `klogd` is running and kernel log file exists at `/var/log/kernel`.

I think reboot initiated by watchdog timer. If memory is good then show us `dmesg` command output and `/var/log/kernel` file.